# Where can I download com.sun.security.* package?

Tags: java, sun, java-security

**Download *com.sun* libraries**

```
new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem()
```

This is what I am using code and it's required necessary libraries and where can I download them ? I did search on google but couldn't find.

Comment: It's part of your JRE... Did you get an error while using it?

Comment: Yes it's showing error for NTSystem() method

Comment: Please paste the error you encountered. That will help us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't compile this code **module** is a package and where can I find **NTSystem()** methode. Futher I have only following class inside **module**                                                                                                                                                          `UnixSystem`                                                                                                 `UnixLoginModule`                                                                                                                                `LdapLoginModule` , etc.

Answer (score 1):

the source code?

```
 $JAVA_HOME\src.zip
```

and about the `com.sun*` package

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: I am using above code in my java program and I couldn't find the **NTSystem()** method in that package.